# GPUDirect RDMA on X86 linux PC, driver build issue

Tags: kernel, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to do GPUDirect RDMA mentioned in the below link. I am using an X86 Linux PC with Quadro M4000 GPU and CUDA 12.0 tool kit. While building the driver and executing CUDA programming, I am getting the following errors.

[GPUDirect_RDMA](https://github.com/NVIDIA/jetson-rdma-picoevb)

When ran command `./build-for-pc-native.sh` to build the kernel module, got the following error:

```
Building modules, stage 2.
** MODPOST 1 modules**
**FATAL: parse error in symbol dump file
scripts/Makefile.modpost:92: recipe for target ‘__modpost’ failed
make[2]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
Makefile:1678: recipe for target ‘modules’ failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory ‘/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-136-generic’
Makefile:19: recipe for target ‘modules’ failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2**
```

To avoid the above error, I ran the command `./build-for-any-no-cuda-native.sh`, then the module is built and loaded.
But again, I get error when I ran the command `client-applications/./build-for-pc-native.sh` for user applications,

```
make: Nothing to be done for ‘default’
```

Ignoring this error when I ran the data access test given in the above github link, I do not get an error while running the command `./rdma-malloc`. But, I get the following error, when I ran this command `./rdma-cuda`,

```
ioctl(PIN_CUDA src) failed: ret=-1 errno=22.
```

Again when I did the `set leds test`, I ran the command `./set-leds 7`, I get an error

```
open() failed: Permission denied
```

but when I use the word `sudo` before the command, I don’t get an error.

Kindly, anyone who knows the cause for the above errors and why they are occurring? reply to this thread.

Comment: Kindly anyone with an idea to resolve this issues, please post

Comment: Kindly reply, 
Driver version - NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.78.01
kernel version - 5.4.0-137-generic
These kernel and driver versions are compatible to build the picoevb module or not?

Comment: Kindly reply,
Driver version - NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.78.01
kernel version - 5.4.0-137-generic
These kernel and driver versions are compatible to build the picoevb module or not?